# Can someone please explain how the replaceAll function works in the following servlet code from App Engine documentation?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am not able to understand what text pattern is being replaced in the replaceAll function in the following sample servlet code from [App Engine documentation of the Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/#Java_Example_Tic_Tac_Toe_application).

```
String token = channelService.createChannel(game.getChannelKey(userId));

// Index is the contents of our index.html resource, details omitted for brevity.
index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ token \\}\\}", token);
```

Many thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this!!

Comment: Simply literal value `"{{ token }}"`. They should have used `.replace()` instead, but ohwell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deconstructing it:

First, since it's a string, any backslashes in the string have to be escaped. So the *string* `\\{\\{ token \\}\\}` equates to the *regular expression* `\{\{ token \}\}`.

Okay, so what does that expression do? `{` is a special character in regular expressions, so the backslashes are there to say that the `{` should be treated *literally* as a `{` character, and the same for `}`.

So it just looks for the literal string `{{ token }}`, replacing it with the contents of the `token` variable.

Comment: What would have happened if we had kept the string as  `\{\{ token \}\}`?

Comment: @user87049: The `\{` and `\}` parts of that are interpreted by the compiler when interpreting the string literal. The `\` in a string literal begins an "escape sequence." Since neither `\{` nor `\}` is a valid string literal escape sequence, the actual string would just be `{{ token }}`. When you gave that to `replaceAll`, you'd get an exception because `{{ token }}` is an invalid regular expression (because again, `{` and `}` are special, but not being used correctly there). More in the [`Pattern` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

That code is replacing the text - `"{{ token }}"` with the value of `token` in the String `index`. The braces are escaped because `replaceAll()` works on regex.

BTW, it can also be done with just `replace()`. No need of regex here:

```
index = index.replace("{{ token }}", token);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit! So, would the following code also have worked?

index=index.replaceAll("{{token}}",token);

Comment: @user87049 No that wouldn't work. As I said, `replaceAll()` takes the regex as first argument, and braces have special meaning in it.